# moment js is returning wrong date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

my code is:

```
moment.locale('hr');
moment( '19 lipnja 2020', 'DD MMMM YYYY' ).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

It is giving wrong output.

```
"19-01-2020"
```

expected output.

```
 "19-06-2020"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

updated:

when I am executing `moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY');` then it is giving me `16 lipnja 2020`

Comment: You've tagged this with [moment-timezone], but are not using [that separate library](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)...

Comment: If you do `lipanj` instead it does work. It does appear on the locale format but I'm not entirely sure what's happening. What's the difference between `lipanj` and `lipnja`?

Comment: `lipnja` seem to be not a valid month name, looking at [hr.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.26.0/locale/hr.js#L81), `lipanj` is the value mentioned in moment.js hr localization for june.

Comment: when I am doing ```moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY');``` then it is giving me 16 lipnja 2020